# Wait for (tex-file) to execute before go on with an elisp script

Tags: latex, subprocess, tex

I wrote a script that reads the `.aux` and `.log` files after some replacements in the `·tex` file (`LaTeX`). To achieve this i did:

```el
(tex-file)
(read-string "Wait to tex-file to complete, then press ENTER:")
```

So I wait for `tex-file` to complete and then I press `ENTER` to make the script go on in reading the (re)genereted files.

I'd like to obtain the same result without the `read-string` command, with the script automatically waits for `tex-file` to compleate.

I read about sentinels but I'm not able to use them. I can't figure out how they works.

Comment: Here are a few examples using process sentinels -- one is for AUCTeX, and two are for *without* the AUCTeX library (one is for Windows, and one is for OSX):  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  The non-AUCTeX example was designed to use in conjunction with a `latexmk.rc` file.  For some nested examples of process sentinels see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548536/penetrating-the-set-process-sentinel-hierarchy-with-let-bound-variables

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I see it in the log buffer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021875/wait-on-shell-command-to-finish-before-executing-another-elisp-command

I resolved by using:

```el
(call-process-shell-command  (concat "latex " (buffer-file-name)) nil nil)
```

that does almost the same and that doesn't use sentinels.